Github Action threw "Error DOM is required."
I upgrade a Symfony project using Docker from version 6.4 to 7.1. Dockefile has snippet of code as bellow to install PHP extension:
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libicu-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev openssl \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd intl bcmath curl xml zip mbstring mysqli iconv pdo_mysql \
&& apt-get purge -y libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libicu-dev
...

Snippet below is the workflow step for Github Action:
...
      - name: Install php dependencies
        uses: php-actions/composer@v6
        with:
          php_version: 8.2
          php_extensions: gd intl bcmath curl xml zip mbstring mysqli iconv pdo_mysql
          version: 2.x
...

During the workflow Github threw an error message in XmlUtils.php at line 49 as screenshoot below:

Any idea?
PS: the project has worked well in my local machine. That error is just happenned when I run Github Action jobs.

The extension also needs to be enabled. This should work with RUN docker-php-ext-install xml.

@Bademeister thanks for tags edition. I enabled the extension already I think. It is in the Dockerfile "docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd intl bcmath curl xml ..."
